# Discovering annotated methods

Tags: java, spring, proxy, annotations

In my Spring application, I have components that use Spring's caching mechanism.  Each `@Cacheable` annotation specifies the cache that is to be used.  I'd like to autodiscover all the caches that are needed at startup so that they can be automatically configured.

The simplest approach seemed to create a marker interface (ex: `CacheUser`) to be used by each caching component:

```
@Component
public class ComponentA implements CacheUser {
  @Cacheable("dictionaryCache")
  public String getDefinition(String word) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I would then have Spring autodiscover all the implementations of this interface and autowire them to a configuration list that can be used when configuring the cache manager(s).  This works.

```
@Autowired
private Optional<List<CacheUser>> cacheUsers;
```

My plan was to take each discovered class and find all methods annotated with `@Cacheable`.  From there I would access the annotation's properties and obtain the cache name.  I'm using `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation()` to get the annotation declaration.

That's where the plan falls apart.  Spring actually wires proxies instead of the raw component, and the annotations aren't copied over to the proxies' methods.  The only workaround I've found exploits the fact that the proxy implements `Advised` which provides access to the proxied class:

```
((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTargetClass().getMethods()
```

From there I can get the original annotations, but this approach is clearly brittle.

So two questions, really:

1. Is there a better way to get to the annotations defined by the proxied class?
2. Can you suggest any other way to discover all uses of `@Cacheable` in my project?  I'd love to do without a marker interface.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need a custom interface. Implement a `BeanPostProcessor` implement the `postProcessAfterInitialization` and use the `AopUtils` to get the actual target class and check for the annotation. You could take a look on how the JMS support works (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L195) then also use the `SmartInitializingSingleton` and in the method you need t implement init your caches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring has a lot of infrastructure interfaces which can help you tap into the lifecycle of the container and/or beans. For your purpose you want to use a [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) and the [`SmartInitializingSingleton`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/SmartInitializingSingleton.html).

The `BeanPostProcessor` will get a callback for all the beans constructed, you will only need to implement the the `postProcessAfterInitialization` method. You can in that method detect the annotations and fill a list of caches.

Then in the `SmartInitializingSingleton`s `afterSingletonsInstantiated` method you use this list to bootstrap/init your caches.

Something like the following (it is untested but should give you an idea).

```
public class CacheInitialingProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, SmartInitializingSingleton {

    private final Set<String> caches = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean);
        ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(targetClass, new ReflectionUtils.MethodCallback() {
            @Override
            public void doWith(Method method) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                Cacheable cacheable = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(method, Cacheable.class);
                if (cacheable != null) {
                    caches.addAll(Arrays.asList(cacheable.cacheNames()));
                }
            }
        });
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
        for (String cache : caches) {
            // inti caches.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a pretty sensible approach.  One minor drawback is that by default the processor will be called for all beans, meaning you could potentially be creating caches for "third-party" components that have their own initialization mechanism.  I think that limiting the annotation search to specific package(s) would help, but brings additional configuration.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the tip on `AopUtils.getTargetClass()`.  Don't know how I missed it, but it allows me to let Spring figure out how to get the target class.  :)

Comment: You can make it as complex as you want, you can check the package of the target class for instance to see if it matches  one of yours if not do nothing.

Comment: Is there any risk that a bean might be lazy-loaded and thus not be post-processed at startup but only later?  Some cache managers don't allow to add caches post-creation (like a Simple Spring Memcached cache manager).

Comment: Well no, because the `afterSingletonsInstantiated` is only called once after all the singletons are instantiated. The `postProcesAfterInitialization` might be called for other beans but the caches won't be touched as that would be happening in the `afterSingletonsInstantiated` method. You could add a field to the class stating that it is already initialized to gain some performance for non-singleton beans.